# Perform action depending on error

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

So, I need my script to keep clicking a button until an error appears; however, depending on the error, the script needs to take different actions.

Can somebody advise what's wrong with the below code? I want it to click a button until an error is displayed; then if an error is thrown, see what text it contains to perform several different actions.

I'm trying to add for basket, then IF the error contains "Sorry" clear the basket, if it contains "unknown" stop the script.

My code is posted below. It keeps failing as the error isn't found (this is normal behaviour as it's not always shown).

```
driver.findElement(By.id("SizeKey")).click();
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("SizeKey"))).selectByVisibleText("Size 12 (UK)");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value=\"15488\"]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("AddItemToBasket")).click();

if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.error > li.last")).isDisplayed()){

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.error > li.last")).getText().contains("Sorry");
    driver.findElement(By.id("basket-value")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("empty-user-bag")).click();
    driver.get(TESTURL);

}
else if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.error > li.last")).getText().contains("unknown")){

    Thread.sleep(90000000);

}
else 
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("SizeKey")).click();
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("SizeKey"))).selectByVisibleText("Size 12 (UK)");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value=\"15488\"]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("AddItemToBasket")).click();
}
```

Comment: how does the code "keep failing"?  do you have a specific error?

Comment: Can you show us what the error looks like? How is it displayed?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to determine what exactly you are trying to do in this scenario and I'm having a hard time figuring out what the intent of some of the code is. I've made a best guess and cleaned up your code to try to accomplish what I think you are trying to do.

What I think you are trying to do:

1. Navigate to product page. (missing from your code)
2. Select a size (and something unknown)
3. Keep clicking Add Item to Basket until you get:

   a. An error that contains "Sorry" at which time you would start over at Step 1

   b. An error that contains "unknown" at which time the script would exit.

...and here's the code...

```
driver.get(url);
boolean error = false;
while (!error)
{
    // driver.findElement(By.id("SizeKey")).click(); // this line shouldn't be needed?
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("SizeKey"))).selectByVisibleText("Size 12 (UK)");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value=\"15488\"]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("AddItemToBasket")).click();

    WebElement errorElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.error > li.last"));
    if (errorElement.isDisplayed())
    {
        if (errorElement.getText().contains("Sorry"))
        {
            driver.findElement(By.id("basket-value")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("empty-user-bag")).click();
            driver.get(url);
        }
        else if (errorElement.getText().contains("unknown"))
        {
            error = true;
        }
    }
}
```